# angularjs $modal avoid multiple instances

Tags: angularjs

I want to know it there is a way to avoid opening multiple modal instances, or by some id or some function?
i want to avoid boolean variables to set true or false when i open, because i have a page with a lot of modals and that is not cool.

In my example if you click "Modal 3" buttonand the "Do stuff button" it opens a lot of instances, i have a plunker working example here:

```
   modalInstance = $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent2.html',
              controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,

              scope: $scope

            });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fkx9faTdDsDjVpgFVKlo?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to refresh the content that's inside the modal, you can simply give your `modal-body` an id, and set the `innerHTML` in your `otherfunction()`

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal-body">
    <h3>MODAL TITLE</h3>
    <button ng-click="otherFunction()" class="btn btn-default">Do stuff</button>
</div>
```

in app.js

```
$scope.otherFunction = function () {
    document.getElementById("myModal").innerHTML = "New content";
}
```

Comment: but i want the modal opened, and just refresh his content, there is no other way?

Comment: its not possible to give modal instance some ID and the access them by the ID?

Comment: Want i need is that when i click "Do stuff" only opens a modal ... is this possible?

Comment: Unclear what you mean. Either you open a new modal with new content (and close the first one), or you refresh the content of the current modal..

Comment: I want a way to prevent the same modal be opened twice, but i dont want to need to close it